# Bug on Angular 12 project

Tags: angular

I've created an Angular12 project, but it doesn't work to get rendered at the browser (`npm start`), and it comes up  this message:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\angular\angular-coder>npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-08T22_06_40_425Z-debug.log
```

Could someone help me to fix that?

Comment: It would help if you formatted that error message in something closer to its originally formatting, rather than in a big unformatted blob. Did you create this project manually, or using `ng new`? It sounds like your `package.json` doesn't have a `start` script.

Comment: Does `npm run start` work?

Comment: Hi pal,

I created it using ng new... maybe something missing or a corrupted lib installed instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the project using Angular's Client, check the package.json file, located at the root of the project.

It should have an entry "scripts" like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

When you type "npm start" it should run this "ng serve" command.

To answer your question, you could:

1. Run "ng serve" instead of "npm start"
   or
2. Fix your package.json file, in case yours is missing the entry "start": "ng serve"
   or
3. Create the project using Angular Client, documentation -> https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0

Comment: Thanks pal, I´ve appreciated it.